# How to open GDI+ Bitmap in readonly mode?

Tags: c++, gdi+, readonly

I want to open a image(jpeg, bmp) using GDI+ using readonly mode, in c++。How can I do this?
Many Thanks！

Answer (score 1):

In the aspect of an **image file**, it is **always** read-only. MSDN' s [Gdiplus::Image::Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> GDI+ does not allow you to save an
>   image to the same file that you used
>   to construct the image.

In the aspect of an **image in memory**, it is **never** read-only. When loaded as Gdiplus::Bitmap or Gdiplus::Image, an image can always be modified - you can't prevent creation of Gdiplus::Graphics that manipulates it.

Answer (score 0):

File I/O in Standard C and C++ has no notion of a read-only file. You just open the file for reading and not for writing. Using iostreams:

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream f( "jgeg.bmp", std::ios::binary );
```

Using C-style streams:

```
#include <cstdio>
FILE * f = fopen( "jpeg.bmp", "rb" );
```